# php ajax dropdown list not updated after editing

Tags: javascript, php

I am new to php and AJAX, I recently assigned to develop leave management system. I struck with a small issue, I fetched data from mysql and displayed in a table format, in that one field is designed as dropdown list , So for i received data and displayed perfectly, now my problem is, i want to select the value from dropdown list and when i click button ,it should update it in the database. My code is

**display_record.php**

```js
function save_row(leave_ID)
{
          
         
 var hods=document.getElementById("hods_val"+leave_ID).value;

 
  
 
 $.ajax
 ({
  type:'post',
  url:'modify_records.php',
  data:{
 edit_row:'save_row',
 row_id:leave_ID,  
 hods_val:hods
  },
  success:function(response) {
   if(response=="success")
   {
   
  document.getElementById("hods_val"+leave_ID).innerHTML=hods;
  
    document.getElementById("edit_button"+leave_ID).style.display="block";
    document.getElementById("save_button"+leave_ID).style.display="none";
   }
  }
 });
}
```

```html
$host="localhost";
$username="root";
$password="";
$databasename="hrdb";
$con=mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password);
$db=mysqli_select_db($con,$databasename);

$select =mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM leavedb");


?>

<table align="center" cellpadding="10" border="1" id="user_table" class="data-table">
<caption class="title">Leave Requested by staff Members</caption>

<tr>
<th>Emp ID</th>
<th>Emp name</th>
<th>Leave Token</th>
<th>Leave Type</th>
<th>Applied Date</th>
<th>Leave From</th>
<th>Leave To</th>
<th>Req.Days</th>
<th>Reason</th>
<th>Available credit</th>
<th>HOD Status</th>
<th>Status</th>
</tr>
<?php
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($select)) 
{
 ?>
 <tr id="row<?php echo $row['leave_ID'];?>">
  <td id="eid_val<?php echo $row['leave_ID'];?>"><?php echo $row['emp_ID'];?></td>
  <td id="empn_val<?php echo $row['leave_ID'];?>"><?php echo $row['emp_ID'];?></td>
  <td id="lid_val<?php echo $row['leave_ID'];?>"><?php echo $row['leave_ID'];?></td>
  <td id="lt_val<?php echo $row['leave_ID'];?>"><?php echo $row['leave_type'];?></td>
  <td id="dor_val<?php echo $row['leave_ID'];?>"><?php echo $row['date_of_request'];?></td>
  <td id="df_val<?php echo $row['leave_ID'];?>"><?php echo $row['date_from'];?></td>
  <td id="dt_val<?php echo $row['leave_ID'];?>"><?php echo $row['date_to'];?></td>
  <td id="rd_val<?php echo $row['leave_ID'];?>"><?php echo $row['req_days'];?></td>
  <td id="rs_val<?php echo $row['leave_ID'];?>"><?php echo $row['reason'];?></td>
  <td id="ad_val<?php echo $row['leave_ID'];?>"><?php echo $row['available_days'];?></td>
 <td id="hods_val<?php echo $row['leave_ID'];?>"> 
  
 <select id="hods_val" name="hods_val"class="aaa">
  <option value="Approved">Approved</option>
  <option value="NotApproved">not Approved</option>
  <option value="MeetMe">Meet Me</option>
  <option value="hods1" selected><?php echo $row['hod_status'];?></option>
</select>
  </td>
     <td>
<input type='button' class="edit_button" id="edit_button<?php echo $row['leave_ID'];?>" value="edit" onclick="edit_row('<?php echo $row['leave_ID'];?>');">
 <input type='button' name="submitt"class="save_button" id="save_button<?php echo $row['leave_ID'];?>" value="Execute" onclick="save_row('<?php echo $row['leave_ID'];?>');">

 
 
 
  </td>
 </tr>
 <?php
 
 

 



}


 



?>


</table>



modify_records.php


<?php
$host="localhost";
$username="root";
$password="";
$databasename="hrdb";

$connect=mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password);
$db=mysqli_select_db($connect,$databasename);



if(isset($_POST['edit_row']))
 

 $row=$_POST['row_id'];
 
$hods111=$_POST['hods_val'];
 

if( mysqli_query($connect,"update leavedb set hod_status='$hods111' where leave_ID='$row'");)
 
  {
   
   echo '<script language="javascript">';
   echo 'alert("Successfully approved")';
   echo '</script>'; 
   
 }
 
 
 echo "success";
 exit();
}

?>
```

Comment: So what is the problem? What isn't functioning as intended? Any errors? Need more information as to what isn't working...

Comment: on server side remove semicolon at end of if condition *if( mysqli_query($connect,"update leavedb set hod_status='$hods111' where leave_ID='$row'");)*

Answer (score 0):

you are not allowed to use more than 1 the same id in the dom.

so instead of this:

```
<select id="hods_val" name="hods_val"class="aaa">
```

give your select a unique id:

```
<select id="select_hods_val<?php echo $row['leave_ID'];?>" name="hods_val"class="aaa">
```

after this you will be able to select the dropdown as follows:

```
document.getElementById("select_hods_val"+leave_ID)...
```